# Why does My HP printer not work with the new version of Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: printing

Ever since I upgraded to the newest version of Ubuntu (12.04) I've had several issues with my HP Deskjet 6300 All In One fax/scanner/printer.
The fax and scanner work fine but the printer does not.  Most often, I can print the first page of a document but then it freezes into the second page.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the `HPLIP` from Ubuntu Software center.

HPLIP (Hewlett-Packard Linux Imaging & Printing) is an HP-developed solution for printing, scanning, and faxing with HP inkjet and laser based printers in Linux. The HPLIP project provides printing support for 2,201 printer models, including Deskjet, Officejet, Photosmart, PSC (Print Scan Copy), Business Inkjet, LaserJet, Edgeline MFP, and LaserJet MFP. (Note: Not all models are currently supported See [Supported Printers](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/supported_devices/index.html) for more information.)

[image: Install via the software center]

[image: HPLIP in Ubuntu Software Center]